# C# and VirtualAlloc, reserving pages

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I'm exploring if it makes sense to use Pinvoke and [VirtualAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to manually manage some large buffers.

Specifically I'd like to reserve virtual pages so I can do things like grow arrays just by committing the next contiguous virtual page, have a scratch memory stack that can grow by committing the next contiguous virtual page, setting a page for read only, etc.  Are there any gotchas I should be aware of?  Like, will NET's normal allocations potentially interfere with this scheme?

EDIT:

Since people think this is too broad, here's my concern specifically:

What virtual address range can I reserve with VirtualAlloc that is guaranteed(ish) not to interfere with the .NET runtime's memory pages?  For instance, one allocation scheme that is common is to place the stack at the top/bottom of the address space and the heap at the bottom/top of the address space, and have them grow towards each other.  If the .NET runtime is doing this, I should be okay reserving pages from the middle of the address range.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using C# to begin with if you want to be doing stuff like this.  Using unmanaged memory is going to preclude you from using most of the language's features.  Also the vast majority of people in the vast majority of situations are not going to benefit from this fine grained level of memory management, and will end up with code that is broken, and for those rare few that get it working, most of *them* are going to see comparable or even worse performance.  The odds of this being a good idea are vanishingly small.

Comment: Manually managing memory is not _that_ hard, especially for large buffers that you expect to exist for the entire process lifetime.  Wrapping the buffers in an unsafe class lets you expose them to the rest of the codebase without issue, so it doesn't "preclude you from using most of the language's features".  And how on Earth is performance going to be worse?  If your performance is bottlenecked by allocating and deallocating you're doing something wrong anyway.

Comment: :) " If your performance is bottlenecked by allocating and deallocating you're doing something wrong anyway." - I think this answers your own question well.

Comment: I'm not doing it for performance.  I don't think I said I was.

Comment: @JayLemmon Managing your own memory creates a *lot* of little problems that can go wrong with almost anything that you do.  Once you're sufficiently experienced, you can reduce the frequency of these mistakes, but with programs that often get large and complex, the probability of mistakes starts to get quite high, due to the shear number of opportunities to make them.  Accessing memory that's been moved, accessing freed memory, allocating the same space multiple times, etc.  In complex programs these are easy mistakes to make .01% of the time.

Comment: @JayLemmon As to the performance, the CLR is generally very intelligent about how it manages memory.  The number of people able to write *more* intelligent memory management applications is fairly small.  In addition, you would need to be programming in some sort of context in which the CLR's memory management model is particularly ill suited to the task, and in most of *those* situations you can simply adjust the algorithm instead.  If you *don't* implement this layer effectively you can end up in the situation where you spend too much time managing the memory, more than the CLR would have.

Comment: I'm a C++ game programmer by trade; I'm perfectly aware of all the issues and benefits of manually managing memory.  I'm not talking about doing all or even most of the allocations like this.  I'm talking about a handful of very large buffers that exist for the lifetime of the process.

Comment: .Net uses the only and same underlying OS memory management - so what kind of differences you are looking for?

Comment: Just allocate managed objects at startup

Comment: I want to manually select the memory address in the virtual memory space for the allocations of the buffers.  This lets me dynamically grow stacks/arrays without needing to copy the data from smaller buffers to larger buffers: instead I just reserve a number of virtual pages for each buffer and only commit them (actually ask for memory) when they actually need the memory.  On a 64 bit address space you can give 64 gigs of dedicated address space to up to 268 million buffers.  All sorts of other options are also possible.  (I think) this is a fairly well known trick with VirtualAlloc.

Answer (score 2):

I've been doing exactly this in a large program of ours. The big memory is used as round-robin buffer for an application that writes large amounts of data to the disk (from sensor hardware). The code that accesses the buffer is written in managed C++, because that has easier access to unmanaged functions, but I guess an unsafe c# block would work fine as well. I can't remember having had any issues with that.

For interfacing with the OS, the manually allocated buffer has the advantage of not moving and being 4kb-aligned. It can be used directly in calls to unbuffered I/O functions.

Here's some piece of code. It's quite some time ago since I wrote that (although it's still in use), so don't ask me about the details (i.e. what that "5% more than initially committed" should be good for...). This code is running in managed C++.

```
try
{

    LPVOID lpvReserveBase;               // base address of the test memory
    LPVOID lpvCommitBase;               // base address of the test memory
    SYSTEM_INFO sSysInfo;         // useful information about the system
    DWORD dwPageSize;               // the page size on this computer

    GetSystemInfo(&sSysInfo);     // initialize the structure
    dwPageSize = sSysInfo.dwPageSize;

    ULONG nCommitPages = nTargetUserSizeBytes / dwPageSize;
    if (nCommitPages * dwPageSize < (DWORD)nTargetUserSizeBytes)
    {
        nCommitPages++;
    }
    nTargetUserSizeBytes = nCommitPages * dwPageSize;
    ULONG nReservedPages = (ULONG)(nCommitPages * 1.05); // reserve 5% more than initially committed

    // Reserve pages in the process's virtual address space.
    lpvReserveBase = VirtualAlloc(
        NULL,               // system selects address
        nReservedPages * dwPageSize, // size of allocation
        MEM_RESERVE,        // allocate reserved pages
        PAGE_NOACCESS);       // protection = no access
    if (lpvReserveBase == NULL)
    {
        ErrLog(E_SHIF_ERR_DMAALLOC_FAILED, "Error: VirtualAlloc reserve failed");
        return FALSE;
    }

    // commit another page.
    lpvCommitBase = VirtualAlloc(
         (LPVOID)lpvReserveBase,    // next page to commit
         nCommitPages * dwPageSize,   // page size, in bytes
         MEM_COMMIT,       // allocate a committed page
         PAGE_READWRITE);    // read/write access
    if (lpvCommitBase == NULL)
    {
          ErrLog(E_SHIF_ERR_DMAALLOC_FAILED, "Error: VirtualAlloc failed");
          return FALSE;
    }

    m_pUserAddr = (LPTSTR)lpvCommitBase;
    pDMADesc->m_dwReservedUserSize = nReservedPages * dwPageSize;
}
catch (std::bad_alloc* exc)
{

    sprintf_s(gsSH_IF_LastErr, 512, "Error: AddDMA: Failed allocate std memory (%d bytes, %s)", nTargetUserSizeBytes, exc->what());
    ErrLog(E_SHIF_ERR_DMAALLOC_FAILED, gsSH_IF_LastErr);
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Glad I'm not totally crazy then :D  How did you allocate the buffers?  Using VirtualAlloc or HeapAlloc or something else?

Comment: I'll check fo you once I get back to office.

Comment: Added some code snippet, more or less 1:1 as it appears in our code.

Comment: Thanks!  Looks like you're letting the OS decide the address for the page, but at least I now know that the .NET runtime doesn't interfere with/is compatible with the normal Windows allocation system.